# JQuery custom validation not working despite being correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, customvalidator

I'm so confused because

1. Ive added the correct libraries, my NON custom validations are working fine
2. I have names on all my tags
3. Spellings are all right

What could it be :(((

I even tried with a different IDE becuase I thought it was buggy. Other than spelling mistakes and forgotten linking js files what possibilty could there be for a custom validator not working? I've tried the regex func they work fine

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("forpassword",
    function(value, element){
        var regex =  /([A-Za-z\d]*[A-Z]+[A-Za-z\d]*[\d]+[A-Za-z\d]*)|([A-Za-z\d]*[\d]+[A-Za-z\d]*[A-Z]+[A-Za-z\d]*)/;
        return this.optional(element) || regex.test(value);
    },
    "Our custom password checker"
);


jQuery.validator.addMethod("foremail",
    function (value, element) {
        var regex = /^.+@cmyemail.on.com$/;
        return this.optional(element) || regex.test(value);
    },
    "Our custom email checker"
);



function myformvalidate()
{
    var form = $("#myform");
    form.validate({
        rules:{

            txtEmail:{
                required: true,
                email: true,
                foremail: true

            },
            txtPassword:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                forpassword: true

            }

        },
        messages:{

            txtEmail:{
                required: "You must enter Email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email",
                foremail: "You must enter a conestoga email"

            },
            txtPassword:{
                required: "Password is required",
                minlength:"Password must be at least 8 characters long",
                forpassword: "Password must contain at least 1 cap 1 digit"

            }

        }
    });
    return form.valid();

}

    //the html code

     <label for="Password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword">

      <label for="Email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail">
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and the reason is really interesting...(?) I linked the validate JS library file BELOW the js file that had the custom validation..and that was causing the error. I had no idea how you link js files in an html document mattered :0